# Convert array of types to union of object type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have these types:

```js
type StepA = // ...
type StepB = // ...
type StepC = // ...

type Steps = [StepA, StepB, StepC]
```

I want to have an utility type `SomeUtilityType<T>` so that:

```js
type StepsCombinations = SomeUtilityType<Steps>
// type StepsCombinations =
//   | { step: 0; value: StepA }
//   | { step: 1; value: StepB }
//   | { step: 2; value: StepC };
```

How should I define `SomeUtilityType<T>`?

**Edit**

If `Steps` is defined as an object

```js
type Steps = {0: StepA, 1: StepB, 2: StepC}
```

this utility using [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) would do the trick (see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysFgIJQLxQERwY9AoUks8YAQqhlmAMJ4HSVXmbEl77j3EDO5A2pYgA0RBCWEMAurnaFKXAPIAjAFYQAxsHIBvAAwAuEUmEBGA5TFQATGeJUAvtLqwA9gFsIAVWABLADbfQABUOAB5cKCgANSgIAA94ADsAEx4tKF5vZLiDBIBXV0UIACcJA1yEgGsE5wB3BKg7QXCoQJj4iGSeCogQZwAzKPJu3oHI3AA+cla4xJSocqrahOaAfig0rmIDQIBuKAA3AENfXIgDSN5AiT2HCJyIfeKdxw5DLio3RUzDn2cEnjQMDcnh8-iCoTkSlUGnGQA)):

```js
type SomeUtilityType<
  V extends { [index: number]: unknown },
  T extends keyof V = keyof V
> = T extends unknown
  ? { step: T; value: V[T]; }
  : never;
```

But I would much prefer avoid defining an object with superfluous keys `0, 1 , 2...`.

I think I could use the above type definition of `SomeUtilityType` if there were some way to get an union of all indexes in the array, like `Indexes<Steps> // --> 0 | 1 | 2`

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysFgIJQLxQERwY9AoUks8YAQqhlmAMJ4HSVXmbEl77j3EDO5A2pYgA0RBCWEMAurnaFKXAPIAjAFYQAxsHIBvAAwAuEUmEBGA5TFQATGeJUAvtLqwA9gFsIAVWABLADbfQABUOAB5cKCgANSgIAA94ADsAEx4tKF5vZLiDBIBXV0UIACcJA1yEgGsE5wB3BKg7QXCoQJj4iGSeCogQZwAzKPJu3oHI3AA+cla4xJSocqrahOaAfig0rmIDQIBuKAA3AENfXIgDSN5AiT2HCJyIfeKdxw5DLio3RUzDn2cEnjQMDcnh8-iCoTkSlUGnGQA)

Comment: How long is `Steps` likely to be?  TypeScript tends to give tuple keys string representations like `"0"` instead of `0`.  If you wanted `{step: "2", value: StepC}`, it would be fine.  If you need `"2"` turned into `2` then we need to write something to do that and it's not straightforward.  If you only need to support tuples up to some maximum finite length, then we can write the utility type with that in mind instead of trying to represent "turn a string into the equivalent number" in the type system.

Comment: Steps would be short, let's say, less than 10 positions. I'm OK with `"2"` instead of `2`. By the way, I've just edited my questions with some alternative solution I found, but still suboptimal.

Comment: Okay, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mapped tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to mostly get what you want.  The only tricky part is that tuple types known keys are, for whatever reason, `string` [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"0"` and `"123"` and not `number` literals like `0` and `123`.  And there is no `StrToNum<T>` utility type that converts the former into the latter.  I've [commented before](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223#issuecomment-410847836) about wanting such things to be able to deal with tuples more programmatically.  Oh well.

If you're okay with string literals instead of numeric literals, then this is straightforward:

```
type SomeUtilityType<T extends readonly any[]> =
  { [K in keyof T]: { step: K, value: T[K] } }[number];

type StepsCombinations = SomeUtilityType<Steps>;
/* type StepsCombinations = {
    step: "0";
    value: StepA;
} | {
    step: "1";
    value: StepB;
} | {
    step: "2";
    value: StepC;
} */
```

---

On the other hand, if we want to get `{step: 0, value: StepA}` and not `{step: "0", value: StepA}`, we need to do the conversion ourselves.  Here is the way I'd probably do it:

```
// only accepts steps up to 99, but you can extend if you want
type Nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
  12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
  23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
  34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45,
  46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
  58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68,
  69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 
  80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91,
  92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99];

type SomeUtilityType<T extends readonly any[]> =
  { [K in keyof T]: { step: Nums[Extract<K, keyof Nums>], value: T[K] } }[number];
```

This uses a hardcoded `Nums` tuple to convert strings to numbers.  It stops at `99`, but you can extend it as far as you need.  You can verfiy that `StepsCombinations` is your desired output:

```
type StepsCombinations = SomeUtilityType<Steps>
/* type StepsCombinations = {
    step: 0;
    value: StepA;
} | {
    step: 1;
    value: StepB;
} | {
    step: 2;
    value: StepC;
} */
```

---

You might not be satisfied with a hardcoded list.  Well, you *could* write a different version using [recursive utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) to do something that *conceptually* works for arbitrarily long tuples:

```
type SomeOtherUtilityType<T extends readonly any[], U = never> =
  T extends readonly [...infer I, infer L] ?
  SomeOtherUtilityType<I, { step: I['length'], value: L } | U> : U;
```

and verify that it works for your example:

```
type StepsCombinations2 = SomeOtherUtilityType<Steps>
/* type StepsCombinations2 = {
    step: 2;
    value: StepC;
} | {
    step: 1;
    value: StepB;
} | {
    step: 0;
    value: StepA;
} */
```

(yes, those are the same type even though the compiler is writing the union in a different order).

*Unfortunately*, the hardcoded-list version is better behaved.  TypeScript has fairly shallow recursion limits, so if you pass in a tuple of a length more than 50-something, the recursive version will break:

```
type Okay = SomeUtilityType<Nums> // fine
type Oops = SomeOtherUtilityType<Nums> // error!
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

So I'd still recommend the version with `Nums` if you need numeric literals.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysFgIJQLxQN5QIYC4oEYoBfAKFElnjACFUMoAjPAJmLPGjgQGE7MBjPAGY27ClzABnOgG0JiADSUE1JRO4BdEtvKcA9gFsIAVWABLADZnQAFQ4AGADw2oEAB7wAdgBNpAJwgsbz1PCxBsTxAZDQA+VBIoehkAaSgzTygAawgQPQAzKBsNPExJKjxkpQA3LAsAVwg8GxSNYmIZTzqDBgg-DQBuHQ5lKW5DBnSscxDJezoYQxNzK1sHRwlJGMGAegAqKF0RyTHuyenPWb4ExKgyhDwAInsHwZuoGvrGkcRBoigAHww10SdzAj3wL2B71qDTwEmovwBQLeoMezEhbw+sJG3ERu222hI222UBCYWw-H4CGA0lB0jqYAOeigAE4WUoGHVgFBcnUoPwsBl3F5vGkCryoAB3QXAMTQAByXWkaBk9iU+CUzCUQiUABYlABWJQANiUAHYlAAOJTsghqggaghagg6gj6ghGgimggWgjWgi25j25iO5ha67MV3Md3MT3Mb3MX3Mf3MW1Ce1CR1CZ1CV1Cd1CT1Cb1CX1Cf1CW26+26x26526126926o3XXXe3W+3X+3W2g32g2Og3Og2ug3ug2eg3eg2+g3+g2243242O43O42u43u42e43e42+43W67G21m+1mx1m51m11m91mz1m71m31m-1m22W+2Wx2Ws6lqupa7qWp6lrepavqWv6lq2iy9oshq1wss6LKuiy7osp6LLeiyvosv6bIDEM4iLKYljWCAdiQM4rgeBAPj+IEwShOEgpRLE8SJJgKRpBk2S5AURQlLc5RQIqBiSDIACiHh+Fg-DAI4lRZDk+SSUqMQaNUMJfM0yStH8RAdF0PR9IMhKHBsJwTJ4UxmDM8wUcs1G0RA6xUJsRL7DZ3l2WcTkXFcKISfYrw3FiXzyIigLoFCqIEJFiTRXCVAIiQfzxYlEnMCl0KfOlPB4gShLWcMCxGAA8sAAAWvSUSsNEcPRwpMb4UABEEZIcZE0RKMYdCeBAVS9HEKDXC47XMV1rG9VAMgAHQrekeS9FAACSShrRtAAyrQAPzXFVEC1Q1fhNe5rXbfQSWbTIADkFhMQA5vVj26YV2J7W0gLGHEeDGFZ-kIMc4xBTMrBoKd52NW5qx0RsMS+QclUBRDDnnJI0PIjcSX5VCaU4nFeMghJ+AFcT8KkwlYX3FAEVE-pxVIKVFUUNVmRYOEMOuVRiOeVJmxQMSUB5OkEBylA1V6FILk1fV8MCy1dHC3EYu9H4eh+AAhESJIeQJZQymYjkhGk0juFSkiSGYY3kt4EAIBEopgHottmAw5Jrek1gQEtQA)